# Python executable scripts installed through `console_scripts` using `pip install -e .` can be found in path but not `pip install .`

Tags: python, command-line, pip

I have my folder structure like this

```
working folder
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── modules.py
├── scripts
│   ├── abc
│   └── def
└── setup.py
```

and tried to write

```
scripts=[
      'scripts/abc',
      'scripts/def'
  ]
```

in `setup.py` but my colleague using Windows complained that it was not easy to invoke. Since I want to make my package cross-platform, I tried to follow the instructions of [the `console_scripts` entry point](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point) but it seemed to require me to put `abc.py` and `def.py` inside `my_package`. However, I want to keep my folder structure. Therefore I tried to write

```
entry_points={
      'console_scripts': [
          'abc=scripts.abc:main',
          'def=scripts.def:main'
      ]}
```

in `setup.py` and `abc` can be invoked if this package is installed using `pip install -e .` (where `.` points to `working folder`), but I cannot invoke it if installed with `pip install .`. It would report some error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/bin/abc", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('my_package==1.0.6', 'console_scripts', 'abc')()
  File "/Users/xx/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/xx/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Users/xx/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/Users/xx/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts'
```

I have no idea what caused this problem. Am I using `console_scripts` the right way? What is the differences between `pip install .` and `pip install -e .`? I have typed `python -m site` and their paths are the same. BTW, I am using Python 3.6.0 installed locally through [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) on macOS 10.12+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `scripts` outside of your main project namespace `my_package`, it will simply not be packaged unless it's been declared as such in `setup.py` (but that shouldn't be done, since this generic name will simply collide with other packages that make this same mistake).  The clear way to fix this is to move all Python modules (e.g. `scripts/abc.py`) into your package's namespace, and modify `'abc=scripts.abc:main'` entry point into `'abc=my_package.abc:main'`, rerun your development/editable installation step (i.e. `pip install -e .`) to see that it still works, then package it up (e.g `python setup.py bdist_wheel` to see that those files got packaged into the `.whl`; or use `pip install .`) to see that it still works.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this, I noticed that without `__init__.py` files, this can also contribute to distribution problems.